# Handling click events on Windows notifications using winotify in Python

Tags: python

I'm using the winotify library in Python to display Windows notifications in my application. I'd like to know if there's a way to handle click events on these notifications and perform custom actions when a user clicks on a notification.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
from winotify import Notification

def on_notification_click(notification):
    # Custom action when the notification is clicked
    print("Notification clicked!")

notification = Notification(
    app_id="MyApp",
    title="My Notification",
    message="Click me!",
)

notification.on_click = on_notification_click

notification.show()
```

In the code above, I'm using winotify to display a notification, and I've defined a function on_notification_click to handle the click event. However, the on_click event doesn't seem to work as expected.

Is there a way to bind click events to notifications created with the winotify library, and if so, how can I achieve this? If not, are there alternative libraries or methods I can use to accomplish this task?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!